# 'UIApplicationMain' class must conform to the 'UIApplicationDelegate' protocol

Tags: xcode, swift3, appdelegate

I got this code from previous developer.. Now I am getting error which says

**'UIApplicationMain' class must conform to the 'UIApplicationDelegate' protocol**

I am posting a block of code below. I am not able to understand why exactly this happening in my code. Kindly please provide the solution if any...

Thanks in advance

```
var appDelegate: HAppDelegate!

@UIApplicationMain
public class HAppDelegate: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

}
```

Comment: Create a new iOS Swift project and look at how the AppDelegate class is declared.

Comment: Th error message is pretty clear: Your class conforms to `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` but it is required to conform (also) to `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Comment: @rmaddy I have checked it by creating new project.. All methods are implemented in this project.. still m getting an error.. :(

Comment: You didn't look very closely. Look at the actual declaration of `AppDelegate`. And as a hint, see the comment by vadian.